# How to get username/password of Netcomm modem?

Tags: router, passwords, modem, reset, username

I am trying to login to a Netcomm modem NB16VM but `admin/admin` doesn't work.

How can I get the correct username/password?

How do I do a hard reset of the modem?  Will that revert the username/password to `admin/admin`?

Comment: Are you sure it's NB16VM? That doesn't seem to have any information. If it the NB16WV, have you [tries this](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=nb16wv+factory+reset&l=1)?